# SQL that will decorate each member of a repeating group with a sequential number

Tags: sql, group-by, repeat, having-clause

I want to decorate each member of each repeating group in a table with a sequential number. So for:

```
id    fk    scheme    code
1     23    2         1234
2     23    2         6666
3     23    2         9876
4     24    2         3421
5     24    5         erty
6     24    7         wert
7     25    2         3490
8     25    2         2389
9     25    5         erfg
```

I would see in my result

```
23|2|1  1234
23|2|2  6666
23|2|3  9876
24|2|1  3421
24|5|1  erty
24|7|1  wert
25|2|1  3490
25|2|2  2389
25|5|1  erfg
```

So fk combined with scheme makes a repeating group. I know I only have up to 5 in a  repeating group, but my test query allows for 3 only. A sequential row number will not do as the decoration, it must be 1 or 2 or 3 only as these are used for cache lookups.

Here is the SQL I came up with using H2 Db SQL syntax:

```
SELECT "identifier", "code" FROM (
SELECT CASE WHEN s1."code" IS NOT NULL AND s2."code" IS NULL AND s3."code" IS NULL 
THEN s1."ident"||'|1' 
WHEN s1."code" IS NOT NULL AND s2."code" IS NOT NULL AND s3."code" IS NULL
THEN s2."ident"||'|2' 
WHEN  s1."code" IS NOT NULL AND s2."code" IS NOT NULL AND s3."code" IS NOT NULL
THEN s3."ident"||'|3' END AS "identifier", s1."code"
FROM (select "ii"."fk", "ii"."scheme", "ii"."fk"||'|'||"ii"."scheme" AS "ident", "code"
from "inidentifier" "ii" group by "fk", "scheme", "code") s1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(select "ii"."fk", "ii"."scheme", "ii"."fk"||'|'||"ii"."scheme" AS "ident", "code" 
from "inidentifier" "ii" group by "fk", "scheme", "code") s2 ON s1."ident" = s2."ident"
AND s1."code" < s2."code"
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(select "ii"."fk", "ii"."scheme", "ii"."fk"||'|'||"ii"."scheme" AS "ident", "code"
from "inidentifier" "ii" group by "fk", "scheme", "code") s3 ON  s1."ident" = s2."ident"
AND s2."ident" = s3."ident" AND s1."code" < s2."code" AND s2."code" < s3."code"
ORDER BY "identifier", s1."code") "cache"
WHERE "cache"."identifier" IS NOT NULL
```

The problem I have is it does not produce any with a |3 on the end, in the example data above there should be 1. It ends up with 23|2|2  9876 and 23|2|2  6666. Different approach maybe?

Thank you in advance

David

Comment: Which database are you using?  (MySQL, Oracle SQLServer, etc)

Comment: Any of the above, ANSI SQL preferred, but concat function is the killer. Using H2 for testing.

Comment: Can you elaborate (edit the question) on what makes records the same group?  I didn't figure it out from the example.  (is id 8 correct in the example output?)

Comment: Sorry, took a while to realised you had spotted an error in my example output

Answer (score 0):

If any DBMS is OK, the natural approach would be `row_number()`:

```
select  *
,       row_number() over (partition by fk, scheme order by id) as rn
from    YourTable
```

This will return a sequential number for each row in a `(fk, scheme)` group.

Comment: row_number() is not supported by H2 so cannot use this method.

Comment: @Olddave: but it **is** ANSI SQL as you requested. And H2 does support row_number() (albeit without order by): http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#rownum

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, we are stuck with V1.3.146 of H2, ROW_NUM() support came in at V 1.3.158. I need to find another way if possible.

Comment: Thinking there might be a way to take the last row in a grouping and use GROUP BY HAVING COUNT(*) = <the number of rows> in that group, then do one for each of the 5 cases (1 row in the repeating group, 2 rows in the repeating group etc.) then UNION them together, but cannot work out the syntax for that.